# dissociate a vector in R

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have data with two variables, i.e. two columns. The first one shows the population the data belongs to and the second column shows the value corresponding to the various experiments for the first population.
It looks like this -

```r
Popn     x-value  
1        2.3  
1        3.6  
1        8.9    
2        5.6   
2        9.6   
3        6.5   
3         .56  
.  
.  
.  
7        5.4  
7         .23  
7        2.1
```

I want to separate out each population and then do a standard statistical analysis on them. How do I separate them out in R. for instance if I want to find the sample size for each population?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: An alternative to `data.table` (which has many advantages), `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::summarize` do a good job, too.

Answer (score 0):

We can call your dataframe as df. Then you can retrieve different subsets in this way: `df1<-df[c(1:3),]`, `df2<-df[c(4,5),]` and so on.